# Why is my daughter's iPhone continuing to charge purchases to my account?

Tags: iphone, apple-id

I gave my iPhone 4 to my daughter and she keeps charging to my Apple account. She signs in with her own Apple ID, but I keep getting charged for apps she is buying.

Comment: Are these charges for new apps or for in-app purchases?

Comment: As @patrix has eluded to, if your CC is not tied to her account (you can check this by going to https://appleid.apple.com and signing in with her Apple ID), then they must be for In-App Purchases, where the apps were originally purchased on your account. The only kink here, however, is that she must know your password as it will prompt her when she makes a purchase, regardless of whether it's an IAP or not. The solution is to remove your CC from her account if it's there and change the password on your own Apple ID.

Comment: A nontechnical solution would be to talk to your daughter about buying stuff..

Answer (score 1):

Go to app store, then at the bottom of the Featured page you will see the Apple ID which is used in it. She might still be using yours.

Signing with her Apple ID to iCloud is not related to the store. Your account might still be there.

Answer (score 0):

Take your credit card off her apple ID.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4062900?start=60&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Note that the iPhone's Settings app has *two* places to specify Apple IDs: `Settings > iCloud` and `Settings > iTunes & App Stores` (that's the layout as of iOS 6).

Ensure that the latter setting contains your daughter's Apple ID and not your own.

Answer (score -1):

When buying apps that cost she can probably be using your credit card number..

Comment: So what would you recommend the asker to do in order to fix the problem?